# Google Maps Android Heatmap Utility tutorial - Cannot resolve method

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm learning how to use the Google Maps API, and I'm trying to implement a heatmap, following [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/heatmap) tutorial, but on their code there is a readItems() method that I cant' figure out from where it's comming.

```
list = readItems(R.raw.police_stations);
```

I've been struggling with that for a day and a half now.
Where this methos is comming from?

Thank you,

```
private void addHeatMap() {
    List<LatLng> list = null;

    // Get the data: latitude/longitude positions of police stations.
    try {
        list = readItems(R.raw.police_stations);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading list of locations.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Create a heat map tile provider, passing it the latlngs of the police stations.
    mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
        .data(list)
        .build();
    // Add a tile overlay to the map, using the heat map tile provider.
    mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are using is loosely based on the source code in the Google Maps demo.  File `HeatmapsDemoActivity.java` contains this definition of `readItems()`.  You can download the map utils and demo by clicking on "downloading a zip file" in [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/setup) or look at line 187 in the [source file](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/HeatmapsDemoActivity.java) at GitHub.

```
private ArrayList<LatLng> readItems(int resource) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(resource);
    String json = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
        double lat = object.getDouble("lat");
        double lng = object.getDouble("lng");
        list.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
    }
    return list;
}
```